# Postgresql, get data according the condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data with  flights, so how to choose the row that has the biggest number for frequency column?

```
from to date                   frequency
XKA LAA 2019-12-17 13:40:00     1
XKA LAA 2019-10-11 13:05:00     1
XKA LAA 2019-08-07 13:05:00     1
XKA LAA 2019-09-28 13:05:00     1
XKA LAA 2019-07-20 13:05:00     3
XKA LAA 2019-08-05 13:05:00     2
XKA LAA 2019-10-06 13:05:00     1
XKA LAA 2019-11-12 13:40:00     4
```

And what if

```
LUU KII 2019-11-12 13:40:00 1
LUU KII 2019-10-06 13:05:00 1
LUU KII 2019-11-12 13:47:00 1
```

I have to choose all of them cuz there is no biggest number between. How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this for `from`/`to` pairs, use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (from, to) f.*
from frequencies f
order by from, to, frequency desc;
```

Otherwise, just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select f.*
from frequencies f
order by frequency desc
limit 1;
```

Or if you want multiple rows in the case of ties, use `rank()`:

```
select f.*
from (select f.*,
             rank() over (partition by from, to order by frequency desc) as seqnum
      from frequencies f
     ) f
where rank = 1;
```

Comment: thank u for your answer. I have an additional question. Can u please look at the question?

Comment: @LanaBash . . . `rank()` should choose ties.  `row_number()` chooses an arbitrary row with the highest value.